# How do i bind click events to elements, which is shown after async data is loaded?

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript

In my route i am fetching some products.

```
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('model', model)
    controller.set('commissionLines', @store.find('commissionLine'))
    controller.set 'products', @store.find('product')
```

The products is shown in my handlebars template, where i print them using the each loop. The description of each product, i want to be hidden, until the product is clicked. So i added a view, which observes the products in the controller, and should add the click events accordingly.

```
MyApp.PropperViewNameView = Ember.View.extend
  applyClick: ( =>
    @$('.button.expand').click (e) =>
      @$(@).parent('tr').next().transition('slide down')
  ).observes('controller.products')
```

Unfortunately no binding happens, if i add "debugger" to the apply click method, i can see that it is triggered before the html is rendered.

How do correctly attach my binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i actually solved this while writing it, as thought about the run loop. 
The problem being that the observes is triggered, before the handlebars binding of the template. So i needed to run my click events after, and this is done by telling ember to run your code in the next run loop, you can do this with "Ember.run.next".

So my view code now looks like this.

```
  applyClick: ( ->
    Ember.run.next =>
      @$('.button.expand').click (e) =>
        @$(@).parent('tr').next().transition('slide down')
  ).observes('controller.products')
```

And here in js

```
  applyClick: function() {
    _this = this
    Ember.run.next(function() {
      _this.$('.button.expand').click(function(e) {
        _this.$(_this).parent('tr').next().transition('slide down');
      });
    });
  }.observes('controller.products'),
```

If there is a cleaner way, feel free to pitch in.